# WordPress co-authors - permalink for co-written post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on project with students.

I created 3 custom post types : `dissertation`, `subject-imposed` and `subject-free`.

Each student can create only ONE post on each custom post type.

Each custom post type get his single page : `single-dissertation.php`, `single-subject-imposed.php` and `single-subject-free.php`.

Each student get three posts. We can switch on each post with a menu for each student : `DISSERTATION`, `SUBJECT IMPOSED`, `SUBJECT FREE`.

But the custom post type `SUBJECT IMPOSED` may have co-authors.

How can I get the permalink to the co-written post and put it in menu of each co-author ?

Example **Maria Stanley** and **Franck Bradley** are co-authors on the same SUBJECT IMPOSED

Menu for student **Maria Stanley** :

- `DISSERTATION`
- `SUBJECT IMPOSED` (co-author, same permalink post with **Franck Bradley**)
- `SUBJECT FREE`

Menu for student **Franck Bradley** :

- `DISSERTATION`
- `SUBJECT IMPOSED` (co-author, same permalink post with **Maria Stanley**)
- `SUBJECT FREE`

I use [Co-authors Plus](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) plugin

I got the authors info of the current post with `get_coauthors();` but nothing about post.

It's not possible to create a query like that ?

```
$get_permalink = get_posts( array(
    'author' => $post->post_author,
    'post_type' => 'subject-imposed'
));
```

I tried with `get_post();` to get post object but I only got one author instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting the data you need from 2 different sources.

get_post(); = the data post
get_coauthors(); = the co-authors

Suggestion:  Use the 2 together.  You could merge the results from each into some kind of array to make it more manageable.
Not elegant, but effective.

Comment: Thank you Lisa. But with get_post(); I got only one author

Comment: Do you get all the co-authors when you use get_coauthors(); ?

Comment: Yes I got all the co-authors with their ID. But I can't associate those ID with posts in return. Because in posts I have only one author

Comment: Does it return the co-authors for that post, or all co-authors?
You should be able to get the co-authors for the post.

Once you have that, you should be able to merge the co-authors with the post info (like the author).
That should give you a complete list.